# Regional settings between SharePoint on premise and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, regional-settings

Both SharePoint online and SharePoint 2019 have the same regional settings.
I retrieved these two values from SharePoint 2019 using rest api:

```
<d:EventDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2023-12-01T00:00:00Z</d:EventDate>
<d:EndDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2023-12-01T23:59:00Z</d:EndDate>
```

Then I created an item with the same values as above:

```
Add-PnPListItem -List "Calendar" -Values @{
    "Title"     = "Test2"; 
    "StartTime" = "2023-12-01T00:00:00Z";  
    "EndTime"   = "2023-12-01T23:59:00Z"; 
}
```

Why do I get different display dates on SharePoint online?
On SharePoint online I get these dates:

```
StarTime: 1/12/2023 01:00
EndTime: 2/12/2023 01:59
```

Why am I not getting the above dates the same as on Premise:

```
StartDate: 1/12/2023 00:00
EndDate: 1/12/2023 23:59
```

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm what cmdlet or API call you are using to retrieve the values from SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online? (once you have added them). Additionally, which versions of PnP PowerShell you are using, in respect of both version of SP?

Answer (score 0):

They might have different time zones.  Also, the user profile's regional settings often overrides the site settings locale and time zone, so check the user's profile.

/_layouts/15/editprofile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider=dfb95e82-8132-404b-b693-25418fdac9b6

Note that every site has its own copy of the user profile, so it can take a few minutes for every site to sync any change you make.

Comment: regional settings of the sites are both the same, I will give it a check and let you know.